# 2.Page ViewController are not fullscreen?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, view, viewcontroller

im on my first app with swift right now. and I want to make 2 Pages.

1.Page -> Button -> 2.Page

it works but the 2.Page looks not like fullscreen ?! more like a Page to slide?
i wann a normal 2.Page like the first one. hope you know what I mean :D thank you for your help.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMpsX.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYl6M.png)

Comment: Do you mean you want the second view controller to slide in and have a back button? You would use UINavigationController with push

Comment: yes that's what I want xD I search for videos rn with UINavigationController. Thank You :)

Answer (score 1):

You just have to go to story board select the 2nd view controller and change presentation style to "Full Screen". Please refer this

[image]

Comment: hey, thank you for your help and your time :) I try it... but nothing happens? same view ? what am I doing wrong ? :(

Comment: Are you using segue to show another controller?

Comment: idk how to send you a pic, I add a new one to my question. im so new to swift sorry -.- I think yes xD I using segue.

Comment: okay i Change it to ,,SHOW,, and it works. :D now I can make a Back Button and I think its done xD now I waiting for the next Problem :D thank you so much :)

Comment: Glad to help,  please UpVote answer so it can help contributers as well

Answer (score 0):

If your SecondViewController is created in programmatic code without the storyboard the following code will work without problem

**Solution1:**

```
class FirstController: UIViewController {

    func presentSecondController() {
        // create instance of secondVC
        let secondController = UIViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)      

        // Change presentation style
        secondController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen

        // Present secondVC
        self.present(secondController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

`

**Solution2:**

**2.a** If SecondViewController is created in the storyboard, you will have to add a StoryboardID to your SecondViewController like the following image:

[image]

**2.b** instantiates secondController instance from the storyboard by adding this code:

```
class FirstController: UIViewController {

    func presentSecondController() {

        // Create storyboard instance from name file
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        
        // Instantiate secondVC from storyboardID
        guard let secondController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondControllerID") as? SecondController else { return }

        // Change presentation style
        secondController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen

        // Present secondVC
        self.present(secondController, animated: true, completion: nil)  
    }

}
```

Comment: hey thank you for your help and your time !!! im on the Storyboard right now. but I think I have to do it with code.. I have some problems with more than one ViewController .. 1. is the view as fullscreen and than the connections. I try what you text to me :)

Comment: you have Discord or ts ? lol. I think I make a wrong second ViewController ?! is this Possible? xD